# Given datetime, filter results by month of that datetime

Tags: sql-server-2008

For sql server 2008: what is the best way to filter results, to return only results that are in the same month as a certain date?

The best I could come up with is the following:

```
-- set up test data
DECLARE @TABLE1 AS TABLE (
    ID INT,
    STRING VARCHAR(MAX),
    DATECOLUMN DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO @TABLE1
SELECT
    0 ID,
    'TABLE1 0' STRING,
    CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-10-13 12:45:00', 102) DATECOLUMN
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'TABLE1 1', CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-9-13 12:45:00', 102)
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'TABLE1 2', CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-10-1 00:00:00', 102)
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'TABLE1 3', CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-10-31 23:59:59', 102)

-- set up constraint
DECLARE @SOMEDATE DATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-10-13 12:45:00', 102)

-- filter
SELECT * FROM @TABLE1
WHERE MONTH(DATECOLUMN) = MONTH(@SOMEDATE)
```

Is this the best way?

Comment: You may need to check it's same year too to avoid false positives in case there is data across different years on your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query will return records where the month of `DateColumn` matches the month of `@SomeDate`, although (as @Jayvee points out) this would be true regardless of the year.  So if that's what you want, your solution is fine.

But you asked whether that was the best solution.  I would say no, because this won't take advantage of any index you may have that includes `DateColumn`.

So this is what I would do, if I were on SQL Server 2008:

```
 declare @someDate datetime  = GetDate()
 declare @startDate date
 declare @endDate date

 -- I want the first day of the month, at 12:00:00AM (no time component).
 -- The DateAdd expression subtracts days, and converting to the Date data type
 -- ensures that I don't have a time component hanging around.
 set @startDate = convert(date, DateAdd(day,- DatePart(day, @someDate) + 1, @someDate))

 -- I want the first day of the next month.  This is easy:
 set @endDate = DateAdd(month, 1, @startDate)

 -- Here's my actual query, that can take advantage of indexes that include DateColumn:
 select * 
 from   Table1
 where  DateColumn >= @startDate and DateColumn < @endDate
```

Note that I said `>=` for start date but `<` for the end date.  That ensures that I'll pick up any date entries for the last day of the month that have a non-zero time component, but won't go into the next month.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for a long-term solution is to create a date dimension table (you can find scripts out there to auto-generate one). The date dim table will just contain a list of dates as far back and forward as you care to go, and it includes columns like DayOfWeek, QuarterOfYear, YYYYMM, etc., so you can join CAST(YOURDATE AS DATE) to the date dim's date and pull nifty date info. Here you can join both of your tables to the date dim and use WHERE t1.YYYYMM = t2.YYYYMM.